# Find sum of first 1000 prime numbers in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, primes

I have written a program which counts the sum of the primes uptill 1000. The program is as follows:

```
limit = 1000

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

sum = 0
for i in range(2, int(limit+1)):
    if is_prime(i):
        sum = sum + i
        count += 1
print sum
```

What changes can I make to find 1000 primes instead of upto 1000 numbers? Also, I am looking for space complexity as O(1) and time complexity as O(n) (As I know other methods can do it :-) such as "Sieve of Eratosthenes" and finding prime while iterating upto sqrt(n) http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/)

Please correct me if I am going wrong some where. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how you get O(n) time, especially when limited to O(1) space.

Comment: @Anonymous, This question has lots to do with that, but it provides lots of info to the OP, but there's some differences...

Comment: The sieve of eratosthenes finds primes in constant space and, what, like n log n time, but it is fundamentally limited to a maximum.

Comment: @jwilner: The sieve of Eratosthenes is neither constant space nor n log n time. I'm not sure what you mean by "fundamentally linked to a maximum" but you can extend the list incrementally, it is just not as efficient. However, you can simply estimate the 1000th prime and sieve out a slightly larger interval.

Comment: @DouglasZare: I think by "fundamentally linked to a maximum" jwilner is referring to the fact that we can decide in the beginning the range of numbers that we want to support (say, up to 10mil). But I agree that "constant space" and "n log n time" is a common misconception, I also often do that. I (and I believe jwilner) feel that it's constant space because once we pick certain upperlimit (say <= 10mil), we can process all primes under 10mil in constant space and n log n time. However, the correct understanding should see that it's the scaling with larger limit which determines the complexity

Comment: @justhalf: As I stated, you can extend the list incrementally, but this is less efficient than the usual sieve of Eratosthenes. See the Wikipedia page. The space needed increases with n. If you call that constant space, what wouldn't be constant space? The prime number theorem says that the nth prime is roughly n log n, so to find the first n primes you need to sieve out about n log n numbers, and with a naive sieve, that means you use n log n space. Then you use about n log n loglog n time, since sieving up to x=n log n takes about x log log x time. I'm not sure where you get n log n.

Comment: First, I already acknowledged that to say it uses constant space is incorrect. Next, I think I consider "n" in the "n log n time" to be the upper limit, instead of the nth prime.

Comment: @justhalf: Reread what I said. You gave me no information that I did not already say. By the way, to sieve up to n, for each prime p, you do about n/p operations, for n loglog n total, not n log n.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Yes, precisely, I said "I already acknowledged" because your comment didn't give new information to me neither! =). And yeah, I think you're correct about it being n log log n.

Comment: Just realized I said constant space and not linear -- whoops. My guess at the time complexity was just that, a guess, but is clearly wrong. Anyway, I'm done spreading misinformation for the night.

Comment: @Deep: You say other methods can do this in constant space and O(n) time. Those are surprising to me. Do you have a link to those methods? Your own algorithm for getting primes up to n is something like O(n^2/log n) because your is_prime method is terribly inefficient, since you use trial division up to p-1 to recognize a prime p though you could stop at sqrt(p). So, your own code is really inefficient, but you say you want an extremely efficient answer.

Comment: @DouglasZare - I was talking about other methods as in "Sieve of Eratosthenes" and finding via iterating upto sqrt(n). I have updated the question. Also, I updated the function to learn in a diff way. :-)

Comment: The sieve of Eratosthenes is not O(n). I already pointed out that using the sieve of Eratosthenes to find the first n primes takes O(n log n loglog n) steps. Again, I would be surprised to see an O(n) algorithm, and maybe you shouldn't be so certain there is one, while your own code is close to O(n^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small improvement based on your code to find `limit` primes instead of `limit` numbers.

```
limit = 1000

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

sum = 0
num = 2
for i in xrange(limit):
    while not is_prime(num):
        num += 1
    sum += num
    num += 1 # sorry, miss this
print sum
```

And you could also use a single loop when looking for certain amount of things you are interested in, it could be just a matter of taste.

```
limit = 1000

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

sum = 0
count = 0
num = 2
while count != limit:
    if is_prime(num):
        sum += num
        count += 1
    num += 1

print sum
```

Comment: The answer should b 3682913. I am getting 2000 with the above code..Any inputs? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forget to increase `num` by 1 when it is a prime :(

Comment: Just one more thing, `sum` is a built-in function of python, using it as variable name would override it. Just be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
def f():
    i = 2
    while True:
        if all(i % x != 0 for x in range(2, i-1)):
            yield i
        i += 1

primes = f()
print sum(primes.next() for _ in range(1000))
```

Or a one liner:

```
import itertools
print sum(itertools.islice(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: all(x % i != 0 for i in range(2, x)), f()), 0, 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish to propose the following algorithm (Sieve of Eratosthenes)

```
n=1000
limit_sieve = 10000
primes = set()
notPrimes = set()
i = 2
while len(primes)<n:
  if not i in notPrimes:
    primes.add(i);
    for notPrime in range(i*2, limit_sieve, i):
      notPrimes.add(notPrime)
  i+=1

sum(primes)
```

Comment: No problem, the limit of the sieve is related to n, through the cumulative distribution of the prime numbers, if n changes then the limit too

Comment: The sieve limit would be huge for so great values of n, it would make the algorithm very very very inefficient

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do what you've requested is probably with `itertools`.

```
def gen_primes():
    for i in itertools.count(2):
        if is_prime(i):
            yield i 

first_one_thousand = list(itertools.islice(gen_primes(), 1000))
```

Shoot, everyone likes a one-liner:

```
first_one_thousand = list(itertools.islice((i for i in itertools.count(2) 
                                            if is_prime(i)), 
                                           1000))
```